(#200) Requires permission: pages_messaging or User associated with the Page access token does not have an appropriate role on the Page
I have all permission replated "me/conversations" this endpoint in graph api but I still get below error "(#200) Requires permission: pages_messaging or User associated with the Page access token does not have an appropriate role on the Page"
My final usecase is I have to connect page with google dilogflow and I have same error in there also
I have try with adding additional replated permissions

"or User associated with the Page access token does not have an appropriate role on the Page" - do they, or don't they?
